# SQL Reporting Use stored proc or query/view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm a software developer not a TSQL or DBA expert, just background. One of my applications uses allot of SQL views for reporting purposes, at this stage (might change) the windows application execute the view and I display the data in a grid/table for reporting purposes. The views are becoming more and more complex and slower, that's one problem. I'm in the process of re-designing the application to use a web front-end for reporting. But my question is what is the best approach with reports in terms of SQL, should my reports be based on Stored Procedure or Views? Any other comments or advice on SQL reporting welcome, like I mentioned I'm a software developer and I try to stay clear of SQL work, but this has become an issue and I thought this is a good time to sharpen my SQL knowledge.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Stored procedure would be a better approach i think..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stored procedures (SPs) are a better choice than views, but views are much better than SQL queries embedded in reports. I know you didn't mention embedded SQL but I'm going to discuss it briefly to give a more rounded answer.

When you embed a SQL query in a report (or an application or anything outside of the database) you are assuming that all of the objects referenced are not going to change in any way. This is firstly a big assumption (and assumptions are bad) and secondly a crippling restriction on the database owner - they *can't* change anything because it might break something somewhere.

When you use an SP or a view to access a database you make the reasonable assumption that the name of the object you are calling (the SP or view) won't change and that any parameter set will remain constant or at least stay compatible. Both approaches hide away the logic of the query from the caller - the logic can be corrected and improved over time without affecting the caller. The entire database can be refactored or even redeisigned as long as the name of the exposed object (and any parameters) remain the same and the caller will never know.

The advantage of using an SP over a view is that you can do far more. For example it's a good idea to validate that parameter values are within expected ranges. If you have a particularly complex query you can break it down into smaller steps, using temp tables for example. Moving on to very heavy queries you could even do interim maintenance steps in an SP, updating stats for example.

I would recommend using SPs for all database access. You might not *need* to now, but it will give you much more scope to change things in the future *if* you need to.

Comment: Thanks @Rhys Jones  for explanation. I think one of our biggest problems is a lack of knowledge, if I look at the views they are all designed with the View Designer and I know there's allot of TSQL that cant open/run in view designer.  I look at it and tell myself as a developer do I use the designer  in VS? I've always preferred to code my object and model and structure code through classes instead of using VS designer that create allot of code behind but also prevent you from doing certain things. I've seen some really good structure and clever TSQL out there, "hand written" tsql.

Comment: "When you embed a SQL query in a report (or an application or anything outside of the database) you are assuming that all of the objects referenced are not going to change in any way." - Why? I would NEVER make that assumption. And I don't see why this matters. If there's a DB change, you're just as likely to need to change a stored proc as embedded SQL. The difference is, if the report needs to change, you can do everything in one place if it's embedded. If it's a stored proc, you have to update the report & the stored proc. And you have to ensure they're always in sync (more room for errors)